# Spring MVC model

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to display the exception occurred in the controller on the view layer. For this I have setup a try catch block like:

```
public String persistUserData( )
{
  try
    {
        //Make DB Call
        // Update DB and get new Data

        model.addAttribute( "updatedData", data );

        throw new Exception("Creating an Exception");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        model.addAttribute("myException", ex.getClass());

    }

    return "myPage.jsp";
}
```

In my view I am trying to print it with `${myException}`, but its not printing anything. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you are testing? `${myException}` will call `toString()` on exception, if it does not have any message, you will get null/empty string. Try: `model.addAttribute("myException", e.getClass());`

Comment: Hi Tomasz, I am going to try your solution.

Comment: Tomasz, e.getClass fetched nothing either on the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am so sorry to tell this, but it works for me...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String omg(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model) {
        try {
            model.addAttribute("name", name);
            throw new Exception("OMG!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("myException", e);
        }
        return "/WEB-INF/foo.jsp";
    }

}
```

And `foo.jsp`:

```
Name: ${name}<br/>
Error was: ${myException}
```

This renders (with default Spring MVC configuration under `http://localhost:8080/app/?name=abc`):

```
Name: abc
Error was: java.lang.Exception: OMG!
```

I swear!

Comment: Sorry Tomasz, I messed it up. Ajax call was overwriting the JSP content :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern :

```
   @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class MyController {
         //catch any exception 
         @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
          public ModelAndView handleMyException(Exception  exception) {
             ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("errorPage);
             mv.addObject("message",exception.getMessage());
             return mv;
                  } 

          @RequestMapping(value="/doSomething", method=RequestMethod.GET)
          public ModelAndView doSomething() {
           /doSomething
         throw new Exception("OMG!");
            return mv;
                  } 

    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the model from the function, which would look like

```
return model;
```

And model should be from type `ModelAndView`.

Comment: But I am able to access other models declared in this method, whats going wrong with exception one.

Comment: The code is still incomplete in the way that you are not showing what happens with the model field. The model field is the important one, it has to be returned by a controller method which is annotaded with RequestMapping.